# Saving a floating value to a google sheet using a script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use google script to make a request and save some data on google sheet.
The problem is when I try to pass some non integer values as parameters in the request.
I think it's something to do with the fact that sheets uses comma for separating decimal from integer while my program sends the numbers separated by a dot.

This is where I am now:

```
const doPost = (event) => {
  console.log(`doPost`, JSON.stringify(event));

  const { parameter } = event;
  const { temp, peso } = parameter;
  var date = new Date();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([date, parseFloat(temp), peso]);
}
```

When I make a post request with parameters: { temp:1.234, peso:1.234 } the result on google sheet is a big mess.

Does someone have any idea how to fix this?

edit:

```
function Test(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var d = 1.23456;

  var date = new Date();
  sheet.appendRow([date, d]);
}
```

This works fine... don't know if it can help you debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Post Data to Sheet

I don't actually do this all that much so I am by no means an expert at it

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e.postData.contents);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  sh.appendRow([data.first,data.second])
}


function sendData(obj) {
  const url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  const params={"payload":JSON.stringify(obj),"muteHttpExceptions":true,"method":"post","headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);
}

function saveMyData() {
  sendData({first:"1.234",second:"1.432"});
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! Sending a JSON object solved it for me. Not sure why it didn't work the other way but this is a nice way around it

Comment: Hey I tried your solution but there is still some problem... The return of the fetch is an error page of google saying "sorry unable to open file at this time." any idea why is as this?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: sorry edited the comment...

Comment: I didn't really worry about it because I'm not returning anything so I didn't really care.

Comment: But the problem is that it does not write! It's not able to access the file I think

Comment: What file are you speaking about?

Comment: If you are saying that it's not writing to the spreadsheet, I didn't experience that problem

Comment: The google sheet file

Comment: Yeah is not writing...

Comment: Like I said I didn't experience that problem it wrote the data just fine.  I removed the response because I don't care about

Comment: Maybe something about how I deployed the project? how did you do it?

Comment: I used the old editor to publish it

Comment: Actually, I just tested it and it works on either one in  manage deployments.  Just pick new version and add something to the description so that you can tell them apart.

Comment: Your executing sendMyData correct?

Comment: Yes I'm executing the sendMyData.

Comment: Followed your suggestion with no result

Comment: I can't help you I'm running on my account right now as we speak

Comment: No problem man, Thank you very much for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out!

The problem was in the setting of the google sheet file.
I'm from Italy so it enters as defult the Italian format. For some reasons this mess up all the new entries. The solution is very simple: change the format to the english one and the problem should solve itself!